# how to patch boto3 lambda invoke on unit test

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, pytest, boto3

I want to add a patch annotation to a unit test so that when my boto3 lambda client tries to invoke instead we will get a mock response, but when i try add the patch to my unit test it get the following error
 `AttributeError: <function client at 0x106a38b80> does not have the attribute 'invoke'`

Here is the attempted test

```
    @patch("functions.my_function.my_function.boto3.client.invoke")
    def test_duck_response_200(self, lambda_mock_response):
        mock_response = Mock()
        mock_response.status_code = 200
        mock_response.content = get_response()
        
        lambda_mock_response.return_value = mock_response
        
        id = "111111111"

        response = invoke_lambda(id)
```

Here is the function

```
lambda_client = boto3.client("lambda", region)

def invoke_lambda(id):
    payload = {"id": id}

    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName=os.environ["MY_LAMBDA"],
        Payload=json.dumps(payload),
    )
    response_content = json.loads(response["Payload"].read().decode())
    return response_content["claim"][0]
```

Comment: Where does `lambda_client` come from? Please include the code.

Comment: its just a global variable in the code, added it in now

Comment: `boto3.client` is a function that returns a client object whose method you want to patch; this should be `@patch("functions.my_function.my_function.boto3.client")` and `lambda_mock_response.return_value.invoke.return_value = mock_response`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets say your `invoke_lambda` is in `my_lambda.py` file. You want to use the patch annotation to mock the lambda_client, not the response. You can then set the `return_value` of the `mocked_lambda_client` to `mocked_response`.

```py
# my_lambda.py
def get_attachment(my_id):
    payload = {"myId": my_id}
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName=os.environ["MY_LAMBDA"],
        Payload=json.dumps(payload),
    )
    return response.status_code
```

```py
# test_my_lambda.py
@mock.patch("my_lambda.lambda_client")
def test_duck_response_200(mock_lambda_client):
    mocked_response = mock.Mock()
    mocked_response.status_code = 200

    mock_lambda_client.invoke.return_value = mocked_response
    response = get_attachment('some_id')
    assert response == 200
```